# Factorizing a block column matrix with element-wise factors

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, block-matrices

Is it possible to factor this matrix

> $$\begin{bmatrix}
>  x_{11} a_{11} & x_{11} a_{12} & x_{12} a_{11} & x_{12} a_{12} & \\
>  x_{21} a_{21} & x_{21} a_{22} & x_{22} a_{21} & x_{22} a_{22} & \\
> \end{bmatrix}$$

as a function of

> $$
> A = \begin{bmatrix}
>    a_{11} & a_{12} \\
>    a_{21} & a_{22} \\
> \end{bmatrix}
> $$

or $\begin{bmatrix} A &|&  A\end{bmatrix}$, possibly without using the Kronecker product?

PS: This is just a simplified $2 \times 2$ version, the dimensions are actually arbitrary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is not possible. But at least this is possible:

\begin{bmatrix} \mathrm{diag}(x_{11},x_{21})\cdot A & \mathrm{diag}(x_{12},x_{22})\cdot A \end{bmatrix}